# How to indicate equal areas in a geometric figure?

Tags: geometry

In geometry, I can use [Hatch Marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatch_mark) to indicate 2 lines have the same length. It is very useful and clear to most people.

How can I do the same for area? Is there a different notation for that? e.g. I have a rectangle and a triangle and I want to indicate they have equal area.

Comment: You can use the same color.

Comment: I've considered using concentric circles, in a manner not-unlike hatch marks.  Alternatively, circles with hatch marks inside them (which, basically, makes them look like simple Roman numeral labels). I can't say that I've seen these in use. Shading same-area with the same color (or monochromatic textures) can work. (Ah, @Salahamam_Fatima beat me to that suggestion as I was typing! :) If the areas overlap, some of these approaches could be hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no standard method to indicate equal areas. The comments have already mentioned some good ideas, but to add one more, a simple (and maybe uncreative) method could be to label the interiors of each shape with a (probably capital) letter: Same letter, same area. If you already have lots of points and/or angles labeled with letters, you could perhaps surround an area-indicating letter with [brackets] to help differentiate it.

But whatever you do, be sure you tell your audience the method you're using beforehand. You should always do that whenever you introduce new notation.